# Scala seems to require 'return' keyword for recursive functions

Tags: scala, recursion

I'm new to Scala and know that the 'return' keyword is redundant. However, when writing a recursive function, the control doesn't return from a call stack when the desired condition is met if the 'return' keyword is missing.

Below is a code to check for balanced parentheses -

Using 'return' (works fine):

```
  def balance(chars: List[Char]): Boolean = {
    def parenBalance(char : List[Char])  :Boolean = {
      parenBalanceRecur(char, 0 , 0)
    }

    def parenBalanceRecur(charSequence: List[Char], itr : Int, imbalance : Int) : Boolean = {
      if (imbalance < 0) then return false
      if (itr == charSequence.length ) {
        if (imbalance == 0) then return true else return false
      }

      if (charSequence(itr) == '(')  {
        parenBalanceRecur(charSequence, (itr + 1), (imbalance + 1))
      }
      else if (charSequence(itr) == ')') {
        parenBalanceRecur(charSequence, itr + 1, imbalance -1)
      }
      else {
        parenBalanceRecur (charSequence, itr +1, imbalance)
      }
    }
    parenBalance(chars)
  }
```

Without return (Successfully computes #1, but doesn't return, fails at #2 with IndexOutOfBoundsException):

```
  def balance(chars: List[Char]): Boolean = {
    def parenBalance(char : List[Char])  :Boolean = {
      parenBalanceRecur(char, 0 , 0)
    }

    def parenBalanceRecur(charSequence: List[Char], itr : Int, imbalance : Int) : Boolean = {
      if (imbalance < 0) then  false
      if (itr == charSequence.length ) {
        if (imbalance == 0) then true else false // #1
      }

      if (charSequence(itr) == '(')  {  // # 2
        parenBalanceRecur(charSequence, (itr + 1), (imbalance + 1))
      }
      else if (charSequence(itr) == ')') {
        parenBalanceRecur(charSequence, itr + 1, imbalance -1)
      }
      else {
        parenBalanceRecur (charSequence, itr +1, imbalance)
      }
    }
    parenBalance(chars)
  }
```

Is this specific to tail recursion? Please help me understand this.

Comment: you've just forgot an else. Every if should have an else... with or without recursion

Comment: You have to make sure that the return value you want is the last value your method produces. Then you don't need (and shouldn't use, for idiomatic Scala code) `return`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As currently implemented, `parenBalanceRecur()` has 3 top-level `if` expressions, they each evaluate to a boolean value, but the rule in scala is that only the last expression of the function is the return value of the function => the first two are simply ignored.

=> in your second implementation:

```scala
def parenBalanceRecur(charSequence: List[Char], itr : Int, imbalance : Int) : Boolean = {
      if (imbalance < 0) then  false
      if (itr == charSequence.length ) {
        if (imbalance == 0) then true else false // #1
      }

      if (charSequence(itr) == '(')  {  // # 2
        parenBalanceRecur(charSequence, (itr + 1), (imbalance + 1))
      }
      else if (charSequence(itr) == ')') {
        parenBalanceRecur(charSequence, itr + 1, imbalance -1)
      }
      else {
        parenBalanceRecur (charSequence, itr +1, imbalance)
      }
    }
    parenBalance(chars)
  }
```

The first expression `if (imbalance < 0) then  false` will evaluate to either true or false, but this expression is disconnected from the rest of the code => the function is not doing anything with that boolean. We could as well write `val thisAchievesNothing = if (imbalance < 0) then  false`. Our `thisAchievesNothing` will hold some value, which is valid syntax, but is not very useful.

Likewise, this:

```scala
if (itr == charSequence.length ) {
        if (imbalance == 0) then true else false // #1
      }
```

will evaluate to another boolean that is equally ignored.

Finally, the last `if... else if... else` will also evaluate to yet another boolean, and since this one is the last expression of the function, that and that only will be the returned value.

Try to re-writing `parenBalanceRecur` as one single `if.. else if... else if ...` expression instead of 3, and then the behavior will be the same as the implementation that uses `return`.

(we tend to avoid `return` since it's a statement that *does* something, whereas the habit is to write functions/expression that *are* some value)

Comment: One more thing: watch out for redundant expressions: `if (imbalance == 0) then true else false` is actually exactly the same expression as `imbalance == 0`

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in some comments, you can not just short circuit the path and return a value without the `return` keyword. `return` is not needed only at the last value of the method. In any case, usually, it's a good practice to avoid short circuits with multiple returns in a method.
In your example, adding two `else` you can construct the path down to the last value of each possible output without using the `return` keyword:

```scala
def balance(chars: List[Char]): Boolean = {
  def parenBalance(char : List[Char])  :Boolean = {
    parenBalanceRecur(char, 0 , 0)
  }

  @tailrec
  def parenBalanceRecur(charSequence: List[Char], itr : Int, imbalance : Int) : Boolean = {
    if (imbalance < 0) then false
    else if (itr == charSequence.length ) {
      if (imbalance == 0) then true else false // #1
    }

    else if (charSequence(itr) == '(')  {  // # 2
      parenBalanceRecur(charSequence, (itr + 1), (imbalance + 1))
    }
    else if (charSequence(itr) == ')') {
      parenBalanceRecur(charSequence, itr + 1, imbalance -1)
    }
    else {
      parenBalanceRecur (charSequence, itr +1, imbalance)
    }
  }
  parenBalance(chars)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides the accepted answer, some things worth considering:

- use @tailrec, so your recursive method gets tail-call optimized by the compiler. Otherwise it can produce stack overflow for very large lists. (Although this might not be the case here, always consider using this annotation when implementing tail-recursive methods).
- `List` in Scala is a singly-linked list, so it's not indexed. Using `cs(iter)` on each recursive call makes your method get the element in linear time for every index. That means you'll get O(n^2) complexity. As an alternative, either use `chars: Array[Char]` which is indexed-based and gives you each element in O(1) or continue using list but switch to pattern match instead.
- minor things: redundant curly braces from `if` expressions with only a single statement inside; `parenBalance` can be removed and call directly `parenBalanceRecur(char, 0 , 0)` as the last statement in `balance`; use default values for `parenBalanceRecur`.

My suggestions in code:

```
  def isBalanced(chars: List[Char]): Boolean = {
    @tailrec
    def balance(cs: List[Char], imbalances: Int = 0): Boolean =
      if (imbalances < 0) false
      else cs match {
          case Nil => imbalances == 0
          case x :: xs =>
            if (x == '(') balance(xs, imbalances + 1)
            else if (x == ')') balance(xs, imbalances - 1)
            else balance(xs, imbalances)
        }

    balance(chars)
  }

  println(isBalanced("()".toList))          // true  
  println(isBalanced("()(())".toList))      // true
  println(isBalanced(")(".toList))          // false
  println(isBalanced("(()))".toList))       // false
  println(isBalanced("((((()))))".toList))  // true
```